# How to display Userform Scrollable Listbox value?

Tags: vba, listbox

In a userform that I create, I add a scrollable listbox (2 columns, 7 rows) and a button.

When I click the button, the value in the third column should change, and the listbox should display the new value accordingly.

Currently particular rows fail to display the new value even I change it already. I also notice that the rows that fail to display the new value are those not showing in the scrollable list box when I click the button.

When I click the button once, the second column of each row is - as expected - increased by 1:
[image]

[image]

However, when I click the button a second time, the rows that are not displayed in the scrollable listbox at the moment, fail to increase by 1 again:
[image]

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    For i = 0 To lstProducts.ListCount - 1
        lstProducts.List(i, 1) = lstProducts.List(i, 1) + 1
    Next i  
End Sub
    
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim iCell As Long
    VBA.Randomize
    With lstProducts
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "120;60;50"
        .List = Worksheets("Product").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Resolved: Adding a code a lstProducts.List = lstProduct.List. Similar to the idea of Me.Repaint.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your loop with this code

```
x = lstProducts.TopIndex
For i = 0 To lstProducts.ListCount - 1
    lstProducts.ListIndex = i
    lstProducts.List(i, 1) = lstProducts.List(i, 1) + 1
 Next i
 lstProducts.ListIndex = x
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, that does not update the display for the row that are hide in the scrollable listbox at the moment I click the button

Comment: You were right.  It only worked if the scroll was never used.  This edited alternate solution does work.  It forces the list item into "view" before it updates it.